# show the existence of a real number

Tags: sequences-and-series, real-numbers, rational-numbers

Let $a_n  > 0$ be any sequence. I want to show that there is a real number $r \in \mathbb R$ such that $ 0 < | r - m/n | < a_n $ for infinitely many points $(m,n ) \in \mathbb N ^2$.

I don't know how to get start. I know that rational numbers are dense in $\mathbb R$, but how can I approximate them to an real number faster than an arbitrary sequence $a_n$? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is the $n$ in $m/n$ the same $n$ in $a_n$ ?

Comment: @lhf Yes, I think so.

Comment: Are you asking the question: Assume $a_n>0$ and let $a_n$ converge to $L>0$. Given any $r>0$ show that the $r$-neighborhood of $L$, or $V_r(L)$ contains infinitely many points in $\mathbb{Q^+}$?,

Comment: I think that it can be any positive sequence $a_n$. I think it should also ask for irrational $r$  otherwise  let $r=1$ and $(m,n)=(n,n)$ for each $n$.

Answer (score 1):

For a continued fraction approximation, see [inequality $(5.4)$](https://www.dropbox.com/s/siuzz9eiyt2e3ah/contfrac.pdf), we have
$$
\left|\,r-\frac{p_k}{q_k}\,\right|\le\frac1{q_kq_{k+1}}\tag{1}
$$
and
$$
\begin{bmatrix}p_{k+1}\\q_{k+1}\end{bmatrix}
=c_{k+1}\begin{bmatrix}p_k\\q_k\end{bmatrix}
+\begin{bmatrix}p_{k-1}\\q_{k-1}\end{bmatrix}\tag{2}
$$
If we set the tail of the continued fraction of $r$ to be $(c_k)$ where
$$
c_{k+1}\ge\frac1{q_k^2a_{q_k}}\tag{3}
$$
We can use $(2)$ and $(3)$ to generate a continued fraction for $r$ from the $a_k$.

When $q_{k-1}\gt0$, $(1)$, $(2)$, and $(3)$ imply that
$$
\left|\,r-\frac{p_k}{q_k}\,\right|
\le\frac1{q_kq_{k+1}}
\lt\frac1{c_{k+1}q_k^2}
\le a_{q_k}\tag{4}
$$

Comment: ?? If $r=(1+\sqrt 5)/2 $ and $k>\sqrt 5$ there are only finitely many $(m,n)\in N^2$ such that $|r-m/n|<(k n^2)^{-1}$. So if  $0<a_n<(3n^2)^{-1}$ for all $n$ then $|r-m/n|\geq a_n$ for all but finitely many  $n$.

Comment: We choose $r$ *after* we are given the sequence $a_n$. Given $a_n=\frac1{3n^2}$, applying $(2)$ and $(3)$ above, we can use the continued fraction $(3;3,3,3,3\dots)$ which gives $r=\frac{3+\sqrt{13}}2$.

Comment: sorry! it was late. i forgot that we are looking for r first.

Comment: @user254665: it is late here, too. In fact, it has just turned 2016! Happy New Year!

Answer (score 0):

Let $I_0\subset [0,\infty)$ be a closed interval. Choose $n_1$ such that $1/n_1$ is less than the length of $I_0.$ Then there will be $m_1$ such that $m_1/n_1$ is in the interior of $I_0.$ We can then choose $0<\delta_1 < a_{n_1}$ such that

$$(m_1/n_1-\delta_1, m_1/n_1+\delta_1) \subset I_0.$$

Now choose a closed interval $I_1 \subset (m_1/n_1-\delta_1, m_1/n_1).$

Lather, rinse, repeat. We obtain nested closed intervals $I_1 \supset I_2 \supset \cdots$ and we can conclude $\cap I_k \ne \emptyset.$

Let $r\in \cap I_k.$ Then for each $k,$ we have

$$0< |r-m_k/n_k| < \delta_k < a_{n_k}$$

as desired.